# Using custom methods or delegates in linq-sql statement

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I am searching the land for an elegant, reusable solution to a problem that has been bothering me for ages. Thus,

Say I have some business logic I use all over the site: (don't get held up as to how simple this is, it could be complex)

```
public DateTime ExpiryDate
{
   get { return DateAdded.Date.AddMonths(ApplicationConfiguration.Rule3ExpiryLengthInMonths); }
}
```

And a Linq statement:

```
groupedByPatient.Count(x =>
                        x.Max(a => System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.AddMonths(a.DateAdded, ApplicationConfiguration.Rule3ExpiryLengthInMonths))
                        <= DateTime.Now);
```

This "expired" logic has got to be repeated as (understandably) Expired is not a column in the db. The net result is that we end up with scattered business logic across the code. Ideally we would have:

```
var count = groupedByPatient.Count(x =>
                        x.Max(a => a.ExpiryDate)
                        <= DateTime.Now);
```

Theoretically as long as you conform to Linq's "c#" rules you should be able to abstract this code out, say:

```
public DateTime ExpiryDate
    {
        get { return System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.AddMonths(
                DateAdded, ApplicationConfiguration.Rule3ExpiryLengthInMonths).D }
    }
```

Comment: I think the confusion here is in your use of groupedByPatient. Is that a result you've already materialised or is it a reference to what would be the DataContext.Patients.[grouping query]. The solutions are quite different.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) on `DateTime`? That way, whenever you have a date you can just call that to get your expiry date:

```
static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime ExpiryDate(this DateTime dte)
    {
        return dte.AddMonths(ApplicationConfiguration.Rule3ExpiryLengthInMonths);
    }
}
```

If I understand your example correctly, `DateAdded` is a date column in your table, from which you wish to find the expiry date. Then, just do this:

```
var count = groupedByPatient.Count(x => 
                         x.Max(a => a.DateAdded.ExpiryDate()) <= DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: The solution i am looking for is not how to do this necessarily, but how to use a c# method within a link statement. This Expire method could be anything. As Linq to sql stands currently this cannot be done, I am trying to think of a nice re-usable solution. The purpose being to abstract re-usable business logic away from Linq statements.

Comment: @GarethReid: Sure, any C# statement can be used with LINQ - but not necessarily with LINQ to Entity Framework, or LINQ to SQL; specifically, if you're using LINQ to *Objects*, you can use any valid C#. The reason is, of course, that for your method to be usable with eg. LINQ to EF, it must be possible to translate your LINQ query into an EF query (which looks much like SQL), but that is not possible in general. So depending on the complexity of your logic, you might have to fetch *all* the objects from db, and then use your C# method in a query on the resulting collection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from the subject of this vs the code samples you've put in, but I'm pretty sure the 2nd here is what you're looking for.

If you just want the result for a materialised query (ie after you've got the data), then use extensions:

```
public static string ToExpiryDate(this DateTime date) 
{
    return date.AddMonths(ApplicationConfiguration.Rule3ExpiryLengthInMonths);
}
```

If you want the result from within a IQueryable (which by your subject is what I think you are looking for), then you can use expressions:

```
public static Expression<Func<IEnumerable<YourEntity>, DateTime>> MaxExpiryDate = (y) => y.Max(
   System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.AddMonths(y.DateAdded, ApplicationConfiguration.Rule3ExpiryLengthInMonths)
);
```

Then your query would look like:

```
var count = groupedByPatient.Count(x => x.YourEntities(MaxExpiryDate) <= DateTime.Now);
```

NOTE: The Func<> MUST be wrapped in Expression<> even though both will appear to work, without wrapping it in expression, the query will force materialisation before it is run. By putting expression around the function we tell EF to do it as part of the query.

Comment: I see what your doing here. I played with expressions for a bit but had no luck. I will have a bit of play and let you know.